# Debug app with inspector in Microsoft Edge

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8, ibm-mobilefirst, microsoft-edge

can anybody know about some inspector like google chrome have for debugging apps? I have an app which I was build with IBM Mobile First and I need some tool which help me debug app on windows phone. Everything works fine for Android and iOS. I was looking for something in google, and only tool which I found was weinre, but this tool isn't working for this project. Maybe someone have same problems?

Comment: You got any solutions?

Comment: @AniruddhaShevle Sorry, but after MS announced they are not going to support windows phone, we just omitted this platform in our projects.
If you are trying to debug your app on windows phone, maybe the solution from cordova official site is going to help you [Windows Phone debugging on IE](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2012/11/15/adapting-your-webkit-optimized-site-for-internet-explorer-10/#qYPwLJDbYKToOveG.97). Best regards and good luck with it!

Comment: Noted. Also, I'm specifically checking for on iOS mobile, wanna inspect MS Edge browser.

Comment: @AniruddhaShevle currently MS Edge is run on the same engine as chrome which is Chromium, here is some information from support: 
`The new Microsoft Edge is based on Chromium and was released on January 15, 2020. It is compatible with all supported versions of Windows, and macOS.` - [Official Support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/download-the-new-microsoft-edge-based-on-chromium-0f4a3dd7-55df-60f5-739f-00010dba52cf)
So basically just try it on Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Try [VORLON](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/eternalcoding/archive/2015/04/30/why-we-made-vorlon-js-and-how-to-use-it-to-debug-your-javascript-remotely.aspx) ?
Also,
you can check
[Debugging MobileFirst Sliverlight and WindowsUniversal App](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2015/08/14/debugging-a-mfp-sliverlight-and-windows-8-1-universal-apps/)

Comment: Thanks for answer, but none works in my case, I'm working on Visual Studio and I don't recommened it to anyone for debbuging a MobileFirst apps.